# How can I set a default value for a column in pgAdmin4?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I am working on a project with PostgreSQL as my database and using pgAdmin4 to interact with the data. I am trying to set a default value for a column but I can't seem to find an option for that. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Don't rely on GUI dialogs. Learn the proper SQL commands. You'll have to put that into a SQL script and put it into your Git repository anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value for column in pgadmin4,

1. right click on table on your left side panel of database tree.
2. click on properties.
3. click on columns tab.
4. In this pane on rightmost column you will have a default and
   you can populate it with values according to your datatype.

Comment: Yes, I found that out, Thank you for you response much appreciated.